# Redirecting the user

Tags: html, url, web

I want to redirect the user from original url to other url

For example:

**www.netflix.com** *to* ***help.netflix.com***

Please let me know how I can change it for a specific directory.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to Apache (or Nginx) configuration file?

Comment: Im not sure, I have a web host with 1&1 if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A domain structured like example.example.com is called a subdomain. Help page (tutorial for 1&1): [Create a subdomain](https://help.1and1.com/domains-c36931/manage-domains-c79822/subdomains-c37588/create-a-subdomain-a594923.html)

Answer (score 1):

You want to add subdomain or a parked domain which can be added via cpanel in your hosting account.